# Laravel cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable how to i generate slug with name and record id

Tags: php, laravel, package, slug

I have used this "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable" laravel package and i need to generate product slug like this

**Name**: Red Shirt

**Slug**: red-shirt-520 (520 is record id for red shirt product)

Following is model function for generate slug but not working correctly

```
public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => ['name', 'tbl_products.id'],
            'separator' => '-',
            'onUpdate' => true,
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: What does "_but not working correctly_" mean? What's the expected output vs. real output?

Comment: can you post your model code ?

Comment: I want to generate URL with table record id like: currently slug is generated based on product name "Red Shirt" slug "red-shirt" but i want to generate it with product id like if for that product record id is 520 then i want slug like this "red-shirt-520"

Comment: in which model you have this sluggable ?

Comment: Like this website is using https://www.dresslily.com/long-sleeve-national-geometric-print-shirt-product2377419.html ===> SLUG "long-sleeve-national-geometric-print-shirt-product" product id => "2377419"

Comment: Products is my model name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In model file add code as shown below and add the plugin details in config/app.php providers array
Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\ServiceProvider::class,

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
    {
     use Sluggable;
     public function sluggable() {
        return ['slug'=>[
            'source'=>'full_name',
            'onUpdate'=>true
        ]];
     }
    }
```